# Django Polls Tutorial Part 3: polls/templates/polls/index.html - What is this code? It's not python

Tags: javascript, python, django

This is straight out of the polls tutorial, I am new to programming, and learning Python and Django, and this looks unfamiliar to me.  Is this JavaScript? also do I need to learn whatever language this is to learn Django?

polls/templates/polls/index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language

Comment: That's Django Template language.

Comment: Yup, that explains it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments it is: Django Template language

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above it is Django template language (the stuff in curly braces) And because it is a template it is inside of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is Django templating engine ( just like jinja in Flask). The stuffs under curly braces "{}" takes the values from views.py in app and present to html file.